# WKWebView does not receive touch events

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview, uiwindow

I am trying to make a floating WKWebview. I want that user can interact with the WKwebview over all the other ViewControllers and that is why I put it inside a second UIWindow. The problem is that it does not receive any touch events from UIWindow(scroll, pan, pinch, or tap,nothing works).

On CustomUIWindow's init method I add my floating WKWebView with its ParanViewController.

```
init(frame: CGRect,
     statusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle,
     viewController:FloatableViewController) {
    
    self.floatingWindowRootViewController = viewController
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.rootViewController = floatingWindowRootViewController
    self.addSubview(viewController.floatingView)
    self.bringSubviewToFront(viewController.floatingView)
    
}
```

I searched on the net and most of the suggestions were sending the touch events to subview. So I override these two functions in my custom UIWindow.

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    
    for subView in subviews {
        if subView is WKWebView {
            return subView.hitTest(self.convert(point, to: subView), with: event) != nil
        }
    }
    return false
}

override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if self.point(inside: point, with: event) {
        self.pointInsideCalled = true
        return floatingWindowRootViewController?.floatingView
    }
    if pointInsideCalled {
        self.pointInsideCalled = false
        return  floatingWindowRootViewController?.floatingView
    }
    return nil
}
```

On my floating WKWebview I did not add any gesture recognizers explicitly and it is set to isUserInteractionEnabled = true. Also I can see that my UIWindow is receiving touch events. The question is how I can send the touch events to my floating WKWebView.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers the above question (which is old now), nor if anyone is trying to solve my problem.... I want a WKWebView interactive, but I also want to be able to track touches.  With this code, I can track the normal Begin, Move, End touch events. Code uses some custom classes, so you can't copy/paste directly.  I don't use storyboard.  In scene delegate I have:

```
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    let window = MyWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

MyWindow:

```
class MyWindow: UIWindow {

var webView: MWebView? = nil
var _lastValidViewIsWebView: Bool = false


override init(windowScene: UIWindowScene) {
    super.init(windowScene: windowScene)
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("") }


override func sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent) {
    super.sendEvent(event)
        
    // If webView's userInteraction ON, then MGestureView does not get events (tap, swipe)
    //      in this case, StudyView will set this class's webView, and if touch originated in this webView, forward events to MWebView manually
    
    if (webView == nil) { return }
    
    if (event.allTouches == nil) { return }
    let touches: Set<UITouch> = event.allTouches!
    if (touches.count != 1) { return }
    let touch = touches.first!
    var view = touch.view

    // view is nil for all touches for WKWebView, except for .began
    if (view == nil && touch.phase == .began) { view =  hitTest(touch.location(in: webView), with: event) }
    
    var inWebView = false
    if (view == nil) { inWebView = _lastValidViewIsWebView }    // scrolling a web view creates events that have null view.  To get around this, keep track of last valid view
    else {
        inWebView = view!.isDescendant(of: webView!)
        _lastValidViewIsWebView = inWebView;
    }
    if (!inWebView) { return }

    
    if (touch.phase == .began) { webView!.touchesBegan2(touches, with: event) }
    else if (touch.phase == .moved) { webView!.touchesMoved2(touches, with: event) }
    else if (touch.phase == .ended) {
        webView!.touchesEnded2(touches, with: event)
        _lastValidViewIsWebView = false
    }
}
```

}

Note: MWebView holds just a WKWebView, plus some logic.